# How to Create 2 Marker with different Info Window in Google Maps Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I just wonderin can i create multiple marker with different info window, in google maps v2 in Android, in my case right here, I try to 3 different marker, 
1. School Marker
2. Direction (fromPosition)
3. Direction (toPosition)

Note : nama_sma >> School name
     : nama_bemo >> Taxi

right now, i can showing all those marker, but the problem each marker is have the same info window, 
This is my xml :

```
 <com.example.frontend.search.MapWrapperLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </com.example.frontend.search.MapWrapperLayout>
```

nb : MapWrapperLayout is wrapper for customizing info Window in my apps

this is my Activity

```
public class Map_result extends FragmentActivity
{   

    GoogleMap map;
    private DBDataSource dataSource;
    private ViewGroup infoWindow;
    private TextView infoTitle;
    private TextView infoSnippet;
    private Button infoButton2;
    //this class for adding button in info window
    private OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener infoButtonListener2;


    LatLng queryPoint;


    LatLng queryPoint_jalur, queryPoint_jalur2; 
  //nama_bemo == taxi
String nama_bemo="";
String latitude_asal="";
String longitude_asal="";
String latitude_tujuan="";
String longitude_tujuan="";
String temp_jalur="";
String temp_jalur2="";
  Double lat_jalur=0.0; 
  Double lon_jalur=0.0;
  Double lat_jalur2=0.0; 
  Double lon_jalur2=0.0;

     String lat, lon;
 String temp, nama_sma;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
            dataSource = = new DBDataSource(this);
            //make the database open
       dataSource.open();

            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        this.infoWindow     = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        this.infoTitle      = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.infoSnippet    = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        this.infoButton2    = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            this.infoButtonListener2 = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton2,
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_beige),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_orange)) {

            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                            }
        };
        this.infoButton2.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener2);
            //method to see the map
            seeMap();

       private void seeMap()
       {
         final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);

           //an array list for getting 2 point (fromPosition) and (toPosition) for taxi
    ArrayList<Sma> list_jalur = dataSource.getallPoint_Jalur_SMA(id_sma);

        for  (int i2 = 0; i2 < list_jalur.size(); i2++) 
        {
           nama_bemo        = list_jalur.get(i2).getNama_bemo();

           latitude_asal    = list_jalur.get(i2).getLat_asal_bemo();
           longitude_asal   = list_jalur.get(i2).getLon_asal_bemo();


           latitude_tujuan  = list_jalur.get(i2).getLat_tujuan_bemo();
           longitude_tujuan     = list_jalur.get(i2).getLon_tujuan_bemo();

           temp_jalur       = latitude_asal + longitude_asal;

           temp_jalur2      = latitude_tujuan + longitude_tujuan;

            String[] splitCoordinate_jalur = temp_jalur.split(", ");
            lat_jalur = Double.valueOf(splitCoordinate_jalur[0]); 
            lon_jalur = Double.valueOf(splitCoordinate_jalur[1]); 

                    //this LatLng (from Position)
                    queryPoint_jalur = new LatLng(lat_jalur, lon_jalur);

                    String[] splitCoordinate_jalur2 = temp_jalur2.split(", ");
            lat_jalur2 = Double.valueOf(splitCoordinate_jalur2[0]);
            lon_jalur2 = Double.valueOf(splitCoordinate_jalur2[1]);

                    //this LatLng (from toPosition) 
            queryPoint_jalur2 = new LatLng(lat_jalur2, lon_jalur2);
               //if the type of taxi is A
               if(nama_bemo.equals("A"))
               {

                 map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(queryPoint_jalur, queryPoint_jalur2)
                .width(7)
                .color(Color.RED));

                 // the question is right here, until here, 
                 //i can create the marker in my map, but all the marker is 
                 //have 1 same info windows. in my case, in this code below, 
                 //I try to make a marker with different infoWindow
                 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(queryPoint_jalur2)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_smk)));

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(queryPoint_jalur)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_smk)));

                     }

               }
       //this loop is getting all school data
      for (int i = 0; i < this.list.size(); i++) 
      {
             //school name
         nama_sma       = list.get(0).getNama().toString();                 
         lat            = list.get(i).getLatitude().toString();
         lon            = list.get(i).getLongitude().toString();

         temp   = lat + lon;

             String[] splitCoordinate = temp.split(", "); 
         a = Double.valueOf(splitCoordinate[0]);
         b = Double.valueOf(splitCoordinate[1]);

             //this is for get the marker of school position
             queryPoint = new LatLng(a, b);

             map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(queryPoint,13));
                 //this is is setup the custom info window
                 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                            infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                            infoButtonListener2.setMarker(marker);
                            mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                            return infoWindow;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                                   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(queryPoint)
                        .title(nama_sma)
                  }
```

The problem is, the 3 Marker (fromPosition), (toPosition), and (School Marker) is showing the same info window, can anybody help me? to create different info window in each marker? any help is needed. Thank You before

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "showing the same info window", I probably didn't get that right.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143969/multiple-infowindowadatpers

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you want to have a different info window for each marker, you also have to create a View for each one of them. Create a Map for the info windows of the markers and use the Marker id as the key, so you can check if you already created the View.

Try with something like this:

```
private Map<String,ViewGroup> infoWindows = new HashMap<String,ViewGroup>();

...

 @Override
 public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    // get or create the infoWindows here instead of in onCreate
    ViewGroup infoWindow = infoWindows.get(marker.getId());
    if(infoWindow==null){
        //if the info window was not yet created for this marker, create it
        infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        Button infoButton = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener2);
        infoWindows.put(marker.getId(), infoWindow);
    }

    // set or update the texts
    ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
    ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet)).setText(marker.getSnippet());

    //why do you need to set the marker to the listener?
    infoButtonListener2.setMarker(marker);
    mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);

    return infoWindow;
 }
```

Comment: yeah i already did this, but all i want to create different info window, not different text..

Comment: What do you mean with "different info window"? Do you want to show all three info windows at once? Or do you want to use a custom View for the info windows?

Comment: in my case, i already show 3 marker at once, but each marker is showing same info window, so i tried to make different info window on each marker

Comment: emm, whats meaning of marker.getId(), and how i supposed to use the method?

Comment: The markers of google map have this method. You can identify the different markers with this. Just use it like in my example.

Comment: can you give an example hoow to identify the different marker? cause i still don't get it...

Comment: The code for this is already in my example. `marker.getId()` only returns the same value for the same marker. Note that the `map.addMarker()` method also returns the added Marker, where you can also call `getId()` to get the id directly after the marker gets created.